# Convert properties of class to single object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these classes in my project:

```
public class A
{
    public A(B b, C c)
    {
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    B b;
    C c;
}
public class B
{
    public B(DataRow row)
    {
        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Property3 "))
            this.Property3 = row["Property3 "].ToString();

        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Property4"))
            this.Property4= row["Property4"].ToString();
    }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4{ get; set; }

    public object MyToObject()
    {
    }
}
public class C
{
    public C(DataRow row)
    {
        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Property1 "))
            this.Property1 = row["Property1 "].ToString();

        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("Property2 "))
            this.Property2 = row["Property2 "].ToString();
    }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to take an object as output from `MyToObject` function that is declared in class `A`; that output object contains all of the properties of `b` and `c`, like this:

```c#
output object = {b.Property3 , b.Property4 , c.Property1 , c.Property2 }
```

Comment: You could return a `Tuple<B, C>`.

Comment: i cant use Tuple, because i'm used juqrey jTable plugin in my project and this plugin takes a list of objects that each object have a properties.

Comment: the output object that you have given makes it look like it is a collection of strings rather than a single object with properties on it? Is that right?

Comment: yeah, collection of int and strings

Comment: Could you explain why exactly do you want to do this? Can't you change the fields `b` and `c` to `public` properties and use `A` directly?

Comment: i'm used jquery jTable plugin in my asp.net project [link](http://www.jtable.org), this plguin take a object with this structure to show result:    return new { Result = "OK", Records = List, TotalRecordCount = Int32.Parse(Count.Rows[0]["Count"].ToString()) };  then in my project, i'm need to show result of query that joins four table in  my pages with jTable, after i'm selected my records, i want to construct an object from each table result with it's class in my project, then add each row of query result to list that named 'List' to return to jTable, plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you've just about got it:

```
public dynamic MyToObject(B b, C c)
{
    return new
    {
        BUserName = b.UserName,
        BPassword = b.PassWord,
        CUserName = c.UserName,
        CPassword = c.PassWord
    }
}
```

Now that you've created a `dynamic` object you can use it like this:

```
var o = a.MyToObject(b, c);
Console.WriteLine(o.BUserName);
```

Comment: i think this way is against with object oriented patterns, and is a bad way, because the class B and C have to many properties, for example more than 15 property!

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, you do realize that your current design is *against* those patterns too right? Both class `B` and `C` have the same properties, such that they could implement a base class with those properties (e.g. `A`). In short, this solution doesn't harm the current design in any way shape or form. **It appears that you're building a combined object for a short period of time** (e.g. a view model) and so you don't need an entire OO structure for that.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, after your response to Tim it's obvious that my assumption was right. A `dynamic` object is **almost certainly** the right approach here, you're sending it client-side for goodness sake.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, and it's worse now because the constructor is setting properties that don't even exist. If you have a set of objects that you need to combine for the purpose of **viewing that data client-side** then you **by definition** need a *flattened view* of that data. Build a `dynamic` object, send it client-side, and forget it. View models **by definition** are not object-oriented, they are flat because they often represent a hierarchy of data behind them that is presented as a flat, nice, interface to the user.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm updated my question again, please check it again.i'm tired :)

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, well that fixes that, but it still doesn't change the approach. You're building a view model. Just build one. You have multiple diverse objects and you need them to be one so you can bind it all on a web page. Flatten it by building a `dynamic` object that can easily be thrown away and go on with life.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari, the method I provided you is a `dynamic` object. When you build an object with the `new` syntax, and define properties and values, without a class name -it's a `dynamic` object. In other words the compiler defines a real class during compilation for the code you see above in my example, but you don't have to, and you don't need to in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class D
{
    public string UserNameB { get; set; }
    public string PasswordB { get; set; }
    public string UserNameC { get; set; }
    public string PassWordC { get; set; }
    public D(B b, C c)
    {
        UserNameB = b.UserName;
        PasswordB = b.PassWord;
        UserNameC = c.UserName;
        PassWordC = c.PassWord;
    }
}
```

and then your `ToMyObject` method can just be this:

```
public static D ToMyObject(B b, C c)
{
    return new D(b, c);
}
```

Or you could also use a `Tuple<B, C>`:

```
public static Tuple<B, C> ToMyObject(B b, C c)
{
    return Tuple.Create(b, c);
}
```

You could also be a bit cheeky and use anonymous objects, but that's very dangerous:

```
public dynamic MyToObject(B b, C c)
{
    return new { UserNameB = b.UserName, PassWordB = b.PassWord,
        UserNameC = c.UserName, PassWordC = c.PassWord }
}
```

Comment: whats your idea about this:
PropertyInfo[] propsB = typeof(b).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo[] propsC = typeof(c).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);